# For loop in Ajax or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have code which return loop from php to ajax via json_encode()

Let me know what I want to do.
there is one table call SMTP. Assume that it has 3 value and I want to fetch that 3 value from table, store in array () and Display it to HTML via AJAX in table format.

So I'm confused where I place my loop, in AJAX or PHP ?
Here is my code.

**PHP**

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from ".$db.".smtp WHERE id = '$user' ");
if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{   
    $array = array($data[2],$data[3]);
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

**JS**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    GolbalURL = $.session.get('URL');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: GolbalURL+"smtp.php",             
        dataType: "html",      
        success: function(response){                    
                $("#divsmtp").html(response); 
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id = "divsmtp"></div>
```

This code return only last value. inarray like ["data2","data3"]

**My Longest way to do**

```
success: function(response){    
        resultObj = eval (response);
        var i = Object.keys(resultObj).length;
        i /=2;
        //$("#divsmtp").html(i);
        var content = "<table>"
        for(j=0; j<i; j++){
            k = j+1;
            if (j % 2 === 0)
            {
                alert("j="+j+" k="+k );
                content += '<tr><td>' + resultObj[j] +  resultObj[k] + '</td></tr>';
            }
            else
            {
                k = k+1;
                var m = j+1;
                alert("m="+m+" k="+k );
                content += '<tr><td>' + resultObj[m] +  resultObj[k] + '</td></tr>';                    
            }
        }
        content += "</table>"

        $('#divsmtp').append(content);
    }
```

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.

Comment: @ShivamPandya — And yet you are doing it anyway…

Comment: @Quentin its an old project and my company do not want to upgrad. What I do ?? :( I also want to change it to PDO. but its not in my hand

Comment: @ShivamPandya You should tell your company!!! dont use these outdated code understand

Comment: @sadiqxs Ya, I allready do that. I'll use PDO from next project :) (y)

Comment: @ShivamPandya which company you work?

Comment: @sadiqxs Sorry I can't say.:|

Comment: @ShivamPandya , did you check my answer?

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird I am currently work with Jay's answer. I'll also try your once and after I vote. :) And how can I get Index ? I only pass value

Comment: @ShivamPandya 1)sure , you will need it at jQuery end while Decoding hson value , that u encoded in php. 2)You get json encoded data in array form so to loop thru it , we use `$.each`  , you automatically get index=> value pair , in it.

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird +1 for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

Because you are always overwrite the `$array` variable with an array.
Use: `$array[] = array($data[2], $data[3]);`

Comment: Will want to create the array *somewhere*, though.

Comment: Yes, It is possible to do If I place my whole table HTML in PHP file's loop, but I do not want to do that

Comment: So any other method to do that ?

Comment: I do not understand your question. You have several ways. Use associative array, and then json_encode that, and then you can loop through your array in success function. Or, you can build your output in the PHP, and then just set the html of #divsmtp in the ajax success.

Answer (score 2):

Use json decoding at jquery end

**EDIT Small way**

```
        $.each($.parseJSON(response), function( index, value ) {
            //Loop  using key value LIKE:  index => value
        });
```

//Old

```
    success: function(response){    
        var jsonDecoded = $.parseJSON(response);            
        console.log(jsonDecoded );   
            $.each(jsonDecoded, function( index, value ) {
                //Loop  using key value LIKE:  index => value
            });


       $("#divsmtp").html(response); 
    }
```

Comment: what I place in "Loop" ? like that ? jsonDecoded[0];

Comment: @ShivamPandya i updated answer chack it , use key value pair.

Comment: Ok, let me try with it

Comment: @ShivamPandya , sure , i used the same many times , to access kay use `alert(index);`  for value `alert(value);`

Comment: Done, See what I do, its long way. is there any sort way. ?

Comment: @ShivamPandya , you need to loop thru it , its their syntax dude , what can we do else , still Check answer UPDATED, I reduced 1 step

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63031/discussion-between-shivam-pandya-and-jquery-angry-bird).

Answer (score 1):

Create the array on the PHP side like this -

```
$array = array();
while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{   
    array_push($array, $data);
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Hello Jay, Your answer solve my problem almost. but its in array format. what i have to do for display it in table ?

Comment: You have to decode the response and place the values appropriately.

Comment: means I decode code and after that create one loop for table and place my values in it. right ?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and ping back to you if I face any issue